# Implement own shell

Tags: c, linux, shell, pipe

Hello and thank you for attention. I am trying to implement my own shell. I have a few questions about my code and about tasks ro resolv. Below I present my previous code and questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void parse(char *line, char **argv, char **argv2)
{
    while (*line != '\0')
    {
        while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\t' || *line == '\n')
        {
            *line++ = '\0';
        }   

        if(*line == '>' && *(line+1) == '>')
        {
            while (*line != '\0' && *line != ' ' &&  *line != '\t' && *line != '\n')
            {
                line++;
            }           
            while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\t' || *line == '\n')
            {           
                *line++ = '\0';
            }
            *argv2 = line;
            break;
        }

        if(*line == '&')
        {
            break;
        }

        *argv++ = line;

        while (*line != '\0' && *line != ' ' &&  *line != '\t' && *line != '\n')
        {
            line++;
        }   
    }
    *argv = '\0';
}

void execute(char **argv, int option)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int status;

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        printf("*** ERROR ***\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        if (execvp(*argv, argv) < 0)
        {
            printf("*** ERROR ***\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else if(option == 1)
    {
        while (wait(&status) != pid);
    }
}

void execute2(char *command, char **argv, char **argv2)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int status;

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        printf("*** ERROR ***\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        //close(1);
        parse(command, argv, argv2);
        int output = open(*argv2, O_APPEND | O_WRONLY);
        dup2(output,1);
        if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit") == 0)
            exit(0);
        if (execvp(*argv, argv) < 0)
        {
            printf("*** ERROR ***\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        close(output);
    }
    else
    {
        while (wait(&status) != pid);
    }
}

int specialChar(char *argv)
{
    int i=0;
    while(argv[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(argv[i]=='>' && argv[i+1]=='>')
            return 1;           
        else if(argv[i]=='&')
            return 2;           
        else if(argv[i]=='|')
            return 3;           
        i++;
    }
}

void  main()
{
    char command[20];
    char *argv[64];
    char *argv2[1];
    char **history = (char**)malloc(20*sizeof(char*));
    int counterHistory1=-1;
    int counterHistory2=0;
    int i;

    for(counterHistory2 = 0; counterHistory2<20; counterHistory2++)
    {
        history[counterHistory2]=(char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    }

    FILE *file;
    file=fopen("history", "w");
    if(!file)
        printf("ERROR");

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Shell -> ");
        gets(command);

        counterHistory1++;
        strcpy(history[counterHistory1],command);
        fopen("history", "w");
        if(counterHistory1<20)
            for(i=0; i<=counterHistory1; i++)
            {
                fprintf(file,"%s\n",history[i]);
            }
        else
            for(i=counterHistory1-20; i<counterHistory1; i++)
            {
                fprintf(file,"%s\n",history[i]);
            }

        fflush(file);
        printf("\n");

        switch(specialChar(command))
        {
            case 1:
                //close(1);
                execute2(command,argv,argv2);
            break;

            case 2:                                //running program in background
                parse(command, argv, argv2);
                if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit") == 0)
                    exit(0);
                execute(argv,0);
            break;

            case 3:

            break;

            default:
                parse(command, argv, argv2);
                if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit") == 0)
                    exit(0);
                execute(argv,1);
            break;
        }
        fclose(file);
        }
}
```

1) When last sign gettin from user is '&' I need to run my program in background. I have read that I can do this if I don 't call wait. Did I do this good or I should change something?

2) If I find ">>" I should redirect output to file. For example I get ls >> output, all catalogs and files should be written to file "output". Unfortunetly, it works only once. After this my program is stopped. I think that proces has never finished and then I can 't write next command. I tried to kill that proces but it didn 't works or I did something wrong.

3) In my shell I should create pipes of any length with the | sign. I have no idea how to resolv that problem...

Thank you for answers and help.

Comment: Subpoint 2) is improved

Comment: You mean you want to write the Interpreter itself? could you please explain what is "counterHistory1,2","history"?

Comment: just a few suggestions - if you fail to open the history file, why don't you crush? and why do you use command of max length 20? that's nothing!

Comment: It is project on university. I should check how many commands user take and I need to save last 20 so that is why I use counterHistory.

Comment: I meant you have a limit of 20 chars PER command. why is that?

Comment: I can change it on 100. Is that any problem?

Comment: not really but you have a bug in specialChar(char *argv). if there is no special char you don't return a value... add "return 0;" or something at the end of the function.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. I correct it but it change nothing

Comment: There are several critical issues with your post. It does not contain a [mcve], and asking multiple questions like this is frowned upon as it makes your question broader and more difficult to relate to for future readers. Please read [ask] and address those issues with an [edit].

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1**

In a shell, a process that is created is child of shell and needs control of terminal, by getting access to stdout, stdin and stderr

```
    signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN);

    setpgid(getpid(),getpid());

    if(background==false) //shell for foreground process
    {
        tcsetpgrp(0,getpgid(getpid())); //access to stdin
        tcsetpgrp(1,getpgid(getpid())); //access to stdout
        tcsetpgrp(2,getpgid(getpid())); //access to stderr
    }
    execvp(command,args);
```